# Docker - ASP.CORE 2.2 application and SSH

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, ssh, dockerfile, sshd

I'm trying to configure my docker container so it's possible to ssh into it (the container will be run on Azure). I managed to create an image that enables user to ssh into a container created from that image, the Dockerfile looks like that (it's not mine, I found it on the internet):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
EXPOSE 2222
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh
RUN echo 'root:Docker' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

I'm using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch` because it's what I need later on to run the application.

Having the Dockerfile above, I run `docker build . -t ssh`. I can confirm that it's possible to ssh into a container created from `ssh` image with following instructions:

```
docker run -d -p 0.0.0.0:2222:22 --name ssh ssh
ssh root@localhost -p 2222
```

My application's Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Application.WebAPI/Application.WebAPI.csproj", "Application.WebAPI/"]
COPY ["Processing.Dependency/Processing.Dependency.csproj", "Processing.Dependency/"]
COPY ["Processing.QueryHandling/Processing.QueryHandling.csproj", "Processing.QueryHandling/"]
COPY ["Model.ViewModels/Model.ViewModels.csproj", "Model.ViewModels/"]
COPY ["Core.Infrastructure/Core.Infrastructure.csproj", "Core.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Model.Values/Model.Values.csproj", "Model.Values/"]
COPY ["Sql.Business/Sql.Business.csproj", "Sql.Business/"]
COPY ["Model.Events/Model.Events.csproj", "Model.Events/"]
COPY ["Model.Messages/Model.Messages.csproj", "Model.Messages/"]
COPY ["Model.Commands/Model.Commands.csproj", "Model.Commands/"]
COPY ["Sql.Common/Sql.Common.csproj", "Sql.Common/"]
COPY ["Model.Business/Model.Business.csproj", "Model.Business/"]
COPY ["Processing.MessageBus/Processing.MessageBus.csproj", "Processing.MessageBus/"]
COPY [".Processing.CommandHandling/Processing.CommandHandling.csproj", "Processing.CommandHandling/"]
COPY ["Processing.EventHandling/Processing.EventHandling.csproj", "Processing.EventHandling/"]
COPY ["Sql.System/Sql.System.csproj", "Sql.System/"]
COPY ["Application.Common/Application.Common.csproj", "Application.Common/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Application.WebAPI/Application.WebAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Application.WebAPI"
RUN dotnet build "Application.WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Application.WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM ssh AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Application.WebApi.dll"]
```

As you can see I'm using `ssh` image as a base image in the final stage. Even though I was able to sshe into the container created from `ssh` image, I'm unable to ssh into a container created from the latter Dockerfile. Here is the docker-compose.yml I'm using in order to ease starting the container:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  application.webapi:
    image: application.webapi
    container_name: webapi
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:5000:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:2222:22"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Application.WebAPI/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=docker
```

When I run `docker exec -it webapi bash`and execute `service ssh status`, I'm getting `[FAIL] sshd is not running ... failed!` - but when I do `service ssh start` and try to ssh into that container, it works. Unfortunately this approach is not acceptable, ssh daemon should launch itself on startup.

I tried using cron and other stuff available on debian but it's a slim version and systemd is not available there - I'm also not fond of installing hundreds of things on slim versions.

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conflicting startup command definitions in your final image. Note that `CMD` does not simply run a command in your image, it defines the *startup command*, and has a complex interaction with `ENTRYPOINT` (in short: if both are present, `CMD` just supplies extra arguments to `ENTRYPOINT`).

You can see the table of possibilities in the Dockerfile documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/. In addition, there's a bonus complication when you mix and match `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` in different layers:

> Note: If CMD is defined from the base image, setting ENTRYPOINT will reset CMD to an empty value. In this scenario, CMD must be defined in the current image to have a value.

As far as I know, you can't get what you want just by layering images. You will need to create a startup script in your final image that both runs `sshd -D` and then runs `dotnet Application.WebApi.dll`.

Comment: And that actually worked some time ago but I forgot to post the answer. You're 100% correct. My solution was: I created a base runtime image where I install all .net-related stuff necessary for running our applications; install sshd and then run a CMD that runs a script starting sshd and our application.